# How Do You Match the Last Comma and Space In a List With Regex?

Tags: regex

For example, say the list is...

**Hello, World, Test, One, Ten**

How would I match the last comma and space (after 1), but also not match "Ten" with it?

I've tried `(,\s)$` and `(,\s)[^,]*$` but that doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: Wy do you need that? You maybe need something else than a regex

Comment: Like this? `,\s(?=[^,]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/Y3olM8/1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match `Ten` you can change the match into a lookahead.

```
,\s(?=[^,]*$)
```

The pattern matches

- `,\s` Match a comma and a whitespace char
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert to the right

  - `[^,]*$` match 0+ occurrences other than `,` till the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

**Note** that `\s` and `[^,]*` can also match a newline.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y3olM8/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(,\s)(?:\w+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CHBgPi/1)